# @Getter @Setter annotation cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, annotations

I am trying to automatize the getter and setter methods in my JavaBean.

Since, method and field naming conventions are described for Beans @ [Naming Convention](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/SCJP/0120__Object-Oriented/JavaBeansNamingConvention.htm), there has to be a way to use this conventions in-order to avoid the boiler plate code such as writing getter and setter methods for every bean. I found one such way [here](http://java-boilerplate.blogspot.com/).

I am using Eclipse Helios IDE with Java SE 6 in my Windows machine. Though Eclipse do provides a way to generate getter and setter methods without explicitly writing them, using annotations would make the code much more cleaner and readable.

However, when I write the following code in my Eclipse I get the following error @ Compile-time:

```
    private @Getter @Setter int price;
```

Error :

Getter cannot be resolved to a type.
Setter cannot be resolved to a type.

How do I resolve it??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@Getter` and `@Setter` are not part of Java. [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html) has annotations with these names, so you should look into how to set it up.

Comment: Have [they](http://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html) used their Annotation Processing Tool for doing this?

Comment: I downloaded the lombak.jar available from [here](http://projectlombok.org/download.html). Added it in my Eclipse and it works fine. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Even though it works, you shouldn't make it a regular practice. Multiple people working on the same code may not have the same setup that you have.

We spent almost a day trying to figure out why something wouldn't compile correctly on our build server and turned out it was caused by some annotations that were auto-generated by eclipes.

Comment: Don't agree with you here. In a way you're suggesting not using external libraries and tools because other people might not know them. If it increases productivity while maintaining readability it's usually a good thing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

People who may still be not getting @Getter and @Setter recognized by eclipse you have to follow the installation instruction for lombok.jar. For eclipse you will have to

On eclipse
Execute lombok.jar (doubleclick it, or run java -jar lombok.jar).

then restart eclipse only then eclipse will recognize the @Getter and @Setter. Simply having lombok.jar in build path may not solve this on eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I resolved by using this dependency in pom.xml.